# $this->getUser() in Symfony controller functional test returns null

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to test a controller that uses $this->getUser()->getUsername(). It complains that getUsername() is called on null.

Here is my client login code from the test class

```
protected function logInAsAdmin(Client $client): void
    {
        $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

        $firewallName = 'main';
        $firewallContext = 'main';

        $roles = [
            'ROLE_USER',
            'ROLE_ADMIN',
        ];

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewallName, $roles);
        $session->set('_security_' . $firewallContext, serialize($token));
        $session->save();

        $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
        $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    }
```

And here is what the controller does:

```
public function home(EmployerRepository $employerRepository, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker): Response
    {
        if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $jobs = [];

            foreach ($employerRepository->findBy(['owner' => $this->getUser()->getUsername()]) as $employer) {
                $jobs = array_merge($jobs, $employer->getJobs()->toArray());
            }

            return $this->render('home.html.twig', ['jobs' => $jobs]);
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why this does not work? I tried instantiating a user object and passing that into the UsernamePasswordToken, but no luck with that either.

using Symfony 4.

The test:

```
/**
     * @test
     */
    public function indexPageIsRenderedWhenLoggedIn(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $this->logInAsAdmin($client);
        $client->request('GET', '/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertRegExp('/Your jobs/', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
    }
```

Comment: Where is `getUser()` method?

Comment: Line 6 of the controller method.

Comment: No, where is it defined?

Comment: That's a method you automatically get access to when extending AbstractController in Symfony

Comment: @Woeler did the `main` firewall provider exist?

Comment: @HastaDhana Yes, it exists.

Comment: would you care to show us the actual test?

Comment: @Jakumi See OP. Updated.

Comment: I believe your user must actually exist (in your case a user with username "admin"). but I used http authentication with an ad-hoc created test user https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html

Comment: Okay, that's a little problematic. The system is using LDAP, which I'm actively trying to avoid using in tests.

Comment: you could provide an in memory user provider for tests only...

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to let everyone know that I solved my problem by injecting the `TokenStorageInterface` into my controller, and getting the username via `$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUsername()`

Comment: That's great, but you should've moved this into a service of some sort. Keep in mind, that there may be no token, or a token may contain a string if user is not authenticated (when using more than one firewall)

Comment: I'm aware, the method is exclusively called in parts of the code where authentication in the form of an actual user MUST have taken place.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return $client from logInAsAdmin function

```
protected function logInAsAdmin(Client $client): Client
{
    $session = $client->getContainer()->get('session');

    $firewallName = 'main';
    $firewallContext = 'main';

    $roles = [
        'ROLE_USER',
        'ROLE_ADMIN',
    ];

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken('admin', null, $firewallName, $roles);
    $session->set('_security_' . $firewallContext, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);
    return $client;
}
```

and use in test:

```
 /**
 * @test
 */
public function indexPageIsRenderedWhenLoggedIn(): void
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client = $this->logInAsAdmin($client);
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    $this->assertRegExp('/Your jobs/', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Comment: I use similar test in https://github.com/ComuneFI/BiCoreBundle/blob/d750c1515d10ef637a93139cbb75e0e7a1fdb726/tests/Cdf/Tests/Utils/BiWebtestcaseAuthorizedClient.php#L35

Comment: See https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token